# How Design a program that must handle multiple "products" like in a production line

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns

I have some problems figuring out how I should design an application.

On a production line there multiple stations. The products will move from one station to the next. Each station will execute some task on the product. 
The tasks should be executed in parallell, so all stations that have a product should execute it's task simultaneously.

I.e. Product1 will enter Station1 and Task1 is executed. Then the production line is forward one station. Product 2 enters Station1 and Product1 enters station2 and corresponding tasks are executed. Each product will be removed from the line in the last/Exit Station. New product will arrive "forever"...

This feels like it's been solved before and maybe there is some
design pattern that will help me achieve this?

At the moment there is 5 stations but it may be more later.

(The program will be an Desktop Application using WPF)

Comment: Are you designing a program that does what you describe? Or is it just a program that monitors/controls what you describe?

Comment: It is a program that does what I describe. The actual Line is not controlled by me. The main "task" that my program is controlling is the actual Task for each station. Some of the tasks are RFID programming, Laser marking,... These task I know how to program, but I can't figure out how to design the overall " structure" of the program...

Comment: The first two sentences of your comment contradict each other. If your program did what you describe, it would need full control over the Line. What it feels like to me, is that your goal is to create a monitoring software, that shows user where various Products are, what tasks are currently active and at what stations.

Comment: They might contradict each other, but that's mostly because English isn't my native language. BUT I don't control the line, but I get signals from the PLC that tells me when the line has a new product and has made a step forward. After that I need to control the different Tasks for each Station...

Comment: Sounds like a pipeline.  You can make the whole pipeline parallel, or expand processing nodes to handle the load for each stage... but conceptually it sounds like each unit of work goes through a single pipeline.

Comment: Be aware of [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx). It's "the observer pattern for asynchronous programs"

Comment: Note that your analogy doesn't extend as far as you possibly think it does. Production lines are effectively the physical manifestation of encapsulation and hardcoded sequential execution. Not every production line is able to handle _any_ product that passes through it. For example, a production line worker who places car doors isn't going to be able to do much if he suddenly gets a wooden chair instead of a car body. There's a difference between a production line where changing the assigned task/intended product is **minimal**, and a **truly generic** production line that handles everything.

Comment: A product being worked on is a thing with state. In software, this is modeled as a variable. A station is a thing that has an input and output. In software, this is modeled as a function. So to build an assembly line, you write a program, composed of functions that accept and modify variables. That's it. The structure of the program would obviously depend on specifics of the work being done, just like an assembly line would depend on the steps and materials involved. I guess what I am saying is that your question is extremely general and difficult to answer because it is so broad.

Comment: _"The tasks should be executed in parallell, so all stations that have a product should execute it's task simultaneously."_ The reason why this is done in real life is because otherwise the other stations would be idling for no reason. But in a single runtime/machine, that is not true. The less stations are working at the same time, the faster the active stations can work. There is little benefit to forced concurrency if you're only interested in the end result and there is no I/O delay to overcome (which argues in favor of asynchronous code, but still not forced simultaneous execution)

Comment: @Flater It sounds to me he needs to control the machines that are at the stations and work on the product. These are slow of course so you want to operate/control more of them simultaneously, possibly performing different tasks depending on the product in the station.

Comment: Is every station performing the same task? Is there no need to keep track of individual products?

Comment: As the question is written, it is quite unclear which specific problem needs a solution. Sounds more like a "shopping for patterns" questions. Voting to close ("needs details or clarity").

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [TPL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl). On the linked documentation page, many useful patterns are explained for situations like yours. Especially the secion 'Dataflow' should be interesting. If I am not mistaken, [this walkthrough](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline) describes the pattern and how to implement it with the TPL that fits to your problem. It even uses the assembly line analogy.

To give a very condensed summary: the `TransformBlock` objects are your stations and you define the task to be carried out by giving it a function that transforms input objects to (multiple) output objects. By linking these `TransfomBlocks` together you get a pipeline, resembling creation process of your product.

Comment: @Andis59 while the analogy of an assembly line works as a model for a software based pipeline, the reverse is not an ideal match: the tracking of real world objects on e.g. conveyor belts by using a software pipeline of the described form suffers from too tight coupling. Too many things can happen to a real world object in and between stations so what looked clean as a theoretical solution becomes a convoluted mess of exception handling in the single stations code. The linked solution works on strings, which can never fall off the belt or be of too low quality to be processed further.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you basically need to implement a program like this:

- Implement all possible tasks in your program (which you said you are able to do);
- Implement a thread in your program that listens to signals from PLC; this thread runs forever, and for each signals, it reads (i) product info and (ii) station info; THEN it redirects to the specific Task in your program;
- If necessary, put multiple instances of your program for each station;
- Suggestion: implement one .NET class library containing all your possible Tasks, and another project to serve as your main program (WPF), that will call the listener thread that will redirect the 'requests'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are describing the control/monitoring of a physical production line there is probably no need to use concurrent programming techniques. A computer is much faster than any physical machine, so even a single thread should be sufficiently fast to update the states for all stations. If there is any compute heavy work to do it could be moved to a worker-thread.

I would suggest modeling the  production line as a series State Machine, probably monitoring hardware sensors to trigger state-changes, and sending signals to the physical machines to do some action. Each station could have a set of standardized states, like "Ready to accept next item", or "failure", so that the different stations can be connected.

If this is driven by hardware sensors you could simply have a common queue for events and have a loop that checks if each event is associated with a state-change, and if so trigger that state change. Somewhat similar to the message pump of UI systems.

It is possible to use c# async/await as a help to write such state-machines, but it is not necessary. You might also want some logic to check if combinations of stations make sense or not, a station producing a squares should probably not be connected to one that expect circles for example.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the .net Queueing foundation.
You should be able to implement your application as a set of queues with each associated activity performing a task then passing the data to the next queue.

If there is a lot of branching and optional steps the .net Workflow foundation would suit the needs of a more complex application.